# Knockoutjs Mapping fromJS keep methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I use KnockoutJs and its great but i need one thing, and i can't figure it out.

1. I make a get request that returns JSon data. The same properties like my Knockout ViewModel.
2. I use the mapping plugin to convert my JSon result into a Knockout viewModel.

That works fine but, off course, i lose the methods defined in my knockout viewModel.

#### How to prevent that so i can use mapping and keep my methods ?

Thank you very much!

## Update

This is just a sample. Maybe there are some syntax errors, but it should show what i am trying to do.

### My JavaScript

```
var MyViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable();
    self.subModels = ko.observableArray();

    self.doSomething = function () {
        alert("Hello from " + self.id());
    };
};

var MySubViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable();

    self.doSomething = function () {
        alert("Hello from " + self.id());
    };
};
```

### My c# Models

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<MySubViewModel> SubModels { get; set; }
}

public class MySubViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

### My Server Result

```
return new MyViewModel
        {
            Id = 1,
            SubModels = new List<MySubViewModel>
                                {
                                new MySubViewModel { Id = 1 },
                                new MySubViewModel { Id = 2 }
                                }
        };
```

Comment: can you show us how you're doing mapping or link to jsfiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle is not really posible. I have tried `ko.mapping.fromJSON` and `ko.mapping.fromJS`. The question is, how to do it right.

Comment: one option would be reapply the model binding each time you change the model data with any ko.mapping.fromJS mapping.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the ko mapping plugin, you can map the json object to a model inside the viewmodel. For example, if you are getting a list of people, you might map the json to viewModel.people. That way you can keep your viewmodel's other properties untouched.

Comment: Ok, right. But what should i do if i want that the people model has a method ? `myViewModel.people[0].someMethod()`

Comment: OK. Can you work up a fiddle and I can show you some options?

Comment: Done, hopefully you understand my problem. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Here is the same question, answered by RPNiemeyer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401799/knockoutjs-adding-observable-properties-and-functions-to-objects-in-a-mapping-g